# jQuery and MsDropdown plugin not posting contents of SELECT

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

Whilst using the MsDropdown, I am getting some strange behaviour and wondered if anyone else has seen the same issue.

[URL to Plugin](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown)

MsDropdown is an jQuery Plugin which allows you to add images/icons to your common and garden SELECT drop down list

Images work fine and appear like they should but when I submit the form it doesn't seem to pass the content of the SELECT statement.

I know this could be a multitude of problems, however, if I disable the MsDropdown - by simple removing the  reference to the js file, the images don't show up, as one would expect, BUT the form does submit correctly - IE. The values of the SELECT dropdown are posted correctly.

Has anyone seen this issue before?

Thoughts and ideas welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you found a solution? I'm having the same problem. Furthermore on android when i click on the drop down i can't see no scrollbars...so you can just click on the (IE) first 6 elements. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use the updated version . you can find it [here](https://github.com/marghoobsuleman/ms-Dropdown)